# Diplay pre-formatted HTML in html.erb pages

Tags: ruby-on-rails

I am creating a new website where some poetries are displayed.
The previous website owner gave me an excel file with 3 columns: title, body and author.

I managed to read from the excel and display title, body and author for each poetry.

HOWEVER the body has been saved into the excel with the HTML TAGS.
Therefore, when I display in my show.html.erb or home.html.erb, also the TAGS are displayed as pure text.

I do not want them to be displayed as text but I want them to be converted/read into HTML tag so that I can keep the formatting of the poetry.

This is what I see on my website (http://localhost:3000/poetries/14):
https://i.stack.imgur.com/EFIRb.jpg

(For moderator: I tried to include the image following the guidance of StackOverflow but I failed)

This is what I want:

```
Io sono la vostra voce, il calore del vostro fiato,
il riflesso del vostro volto,
i vani palpiti di vane ali...
fa lo stesso, sino alla fine io sto con voi.

Ecco perché amate così cúpidi
me, nel mio peccato e nel mio male,
perché affidaste a me ciecamente
il migliore dei vostri figli;
perché nemmeno chiedeste di lui,
mai, e la mia casa vuota per sempre
velaste di fumose lodi.
E dicono: non ci si può fondere più strettamente,
non si può amare più perdutamente...

Come vuole l’ombra staccarsi dal corpo,
come vuole la carne separarsi dall’anima,
così io adesso voglio essere scordata.
```

My show.html.erb contains only:

```
<%= @poetry.body %>
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Although you can label a string as `html_safe` this is dangerous to do if you can't ensure the data's origin.

But you can use `sanitize` to ensure only safe tags are included in the string. For example, if it's `<br>` tags that you want to preserve, do

```
<%= sanitize(@poetry.body, tags: %w(br)) %>
```

Answer (score 1):

You can do:

```
<%= raw @poetry.body %>
```

OR(preferred)

```
<%= @poetry.body.html_safe %>
```

This will convert your text to HTML output.

Answer (score 0):

Try:

```
<%= @poetry.body.html_safe %>
```

or

```
<%=h @poetry.body %>
```